# Can a hash be made readonly?

Tags: powershell

Running the below code, I assume `$CONST_HASH` can't be edited.

```
Set-Variable -Name CONST_HASH -Value @{a=1} -Option Constant
```

If I try to reset the variable it fails

```
$CONST_HASH2 = @{}
```

But I can append to, or edit its values.

```
$CONST_HASH.A = 10
$CONST_HASH.B = 2
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: `@{a=1}` -> `([ordered]@{a=1}).AsReadOnly()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically that is how reference types work in .NET. When you make variable read-only that mean, you can not make variable to reference different object, but you still can mutate referenced object, if it is not immutable. There are no easy way to make arbitrary object read-only, unless object support that itself.

Usually that involves wrapping objects with read-only wrappers. For generic collections you can use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1) and [`ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2) classes.

I do not know easy way to make [`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable) read-only, but you can use [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary) instead, which provide build-in support for making it read-only:

```
$ReadOnlyDictionary = ([ordered]@{ a = 1 }).AsReadOnly()
```

Note: this does not work transitively, if you put mutable object in read-only collection, it still be mutable. For example for arrays:

```
$Dictionary = ([ordered]@{ Array = 1, 2, 3 }).AsReadOnly()
```

You can not assign new array to the dictionary:

```
$Dictionary['Array'] = 4, 5, 6 # Error
```

But you still can modify array, which is stored here:

```
$Dictionary['Array'][0] = 4
$Dictionary['Array'][1] = 5
$Dictionary['Array'][2] = 6
```

To make array read-only as well, you need to wrap it too:

```
$Dictionary = ([ordered]@{ Array = [Array]::AsReadOnly((1, 2, 3)) }).AsReadOnly()
```

Note: as arrays in .NET do not have build-in support for being read-only, `[Array]::AsReadOnly` does not return an array but a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapper for it.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a shortcoming of working with objects instead of value types like string.

```
Set-Variable -Name CONST_HASH4  -Option ReadOnly -Value ([string]1)
Set-Variable -Name CONST_HASH5  -Option Constant -Value ([string]1)
```

Both in fact create a variable that will not be written to.

If you look at the variable you are loading by

```
$CONST_HASH | gm
```

You can see it is a collection.

I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable?view=powershell-6) that explains this behavior.